# Is it always possible to choose two subsets with the same sum?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Given two positive integers $n, m$, let $A$ be a multiset of $n$ integers taken from { $ 1,2,\cdots, m$ }, and $B$ be a multiset of $m$ integers taken from { $1,2,\cdots,n$ }.

Is it always possible to choose two nonempty subsets from $A$ and $B$ respectively, such that their sums are equal?

I cannot either prove or disprove it. Trying some examples made me conjecture that it is true.

Comment: This is the problem A4 in the 54th Putnam exam. I guess you can find a solution here http://www.mat.itu.edu.tr/gungor/IMO/www.kalva.demon.co.uk/putnam/putn93.html
I also suggest artofproblemsolving.com as a better forum to discuss questions at this level.

Comment: Gjergji's link no longer works but problem A4 from the 54th Putnam (1993), in which $\{n,m\} = \{19,93\}$, can be found here: http://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol934.html